# How to do a fuzzy match in PySpark UDF?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-comparison, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying to run following code to generate an additional col in pyspark df. The idea is to take the col from pyspark df and get the max of the scores by comparing the col with the list of keywords I have. (e.g. choices)

```
def get_max_sore(col):
    choices = ['hello','hello world','world hello']
    return max(process.extractOne(col, choices, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio), process.extractOne(col, choices, scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio), process.extractOne(col, choices))

from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
get_max_udf = udf(get_max_sore, StringType())
sdf_1 = sparkDf.withColumn('new_col', get_max_udf(sparkDf.col))
sdf_1.show()
```

The last statement `sdf_1.show()` gives me an error.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1972.showString.
.
.
.
.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fuzzywuzzy'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

This is the first time I am working with spark and how it works. Please help.
What functions can I use to perform the same, like fuzzy matching the col value with `choices = ['hello','hello world','world hello']`. Also, fuzzy package is installed in all the nodes.

Comment: You sure you have the module `fuzzywuzzy` installed??

Comment: more specifically, to complete Preetham's comment, do you have fuzzywuzzy installed on each and every node ?

Comment: @Steven I checked and it is installed on all the nodes.

Comment: and you only have one python installed ? no virtual env ? the python you are checking on every node is the same that spark is using ?

Comment: @Steven ya. I have other virtual envs. I am checking on the same env for all the nodes and the package is installed on all of them.

Comment: @Steven Thanks. There are some other issues with the nodes I am working on. But I tried it on my personal computer and everything worked fine. I guess the issue is with the nodes or env.

Answer (score 0):

Install  fuzzywuzzy using below command

> pip install fuzzywuzzy

Comment: Have you seen this part of question: `Also, fuzzy package is installed in all the nodes.`?