# Fuzzy Matching in PySpark Failed : TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, fuzzywuzzy

I have two Redshift Tables each containing a column which stores email_addresses.
I am using the FuzzyWuzzy library for String Matching between these two columns.
I have read about FuzzyWuzzy [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/string-matching-with-fuzzywuzzy-e982c61f8a84) and the PySpark logic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59711060/how-to-do-a-fuzzy-match-in-pyspark-udf).
This is my FuzzyWuzzy logic in Pyspark script :

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("max_name", StringType(), False),
    StructField("max_score", IntegerType(), False)
])

second_table_email = second_redshift_table_df.select("email_address")
second_table_email_list = list(second_table_email)

def get_best_email_match(first_col):
    choices = second_table_email_list
    return process.extractOne(first_col, choices, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)

get_best_email_udf = udf(get_best_email, schema)
sdf_1 = first_redshift_table_df.withColumn('new_col', get_best_email_udf(first_redshift_table_df.email_address))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 437, in dumps
    return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, pickle_protocol)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 101, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 540, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 437, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 774, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 722, in save_function
    *self._dynamic_function_reduce(obj), obj=obj
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 664, in _save_reduce_pickle5
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 774, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 819, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 846, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 890, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 524, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 437, in dumps
    return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, pickle_protocol)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 101, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 540, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 437, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 774, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 722, in save_function
    *self._dynamic_function_reduce(obj), obj=obj
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 664, in _save_reduce_pickle5
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 774, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 819, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 846, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 890, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/pickle.py", line 524, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py", line 199, in wrapper
    return self(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py", line 177, in __call__
    judf = self._judf
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py", line 161, in _judf
    self._judf_placeholder = self._create_judf()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py", line 170, in _create_judf
    wrapped_func = _wrap_function(sc, self.func, self.returnType)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py", line 34, in _wrap_function
    pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2814, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
    pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 447, in dumps
    raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please help.